# Creating links to ontology nodes

Tags: uri, semantic-web, triples

Let's say that, being abstract from any language, we have some ontology made of triples (e.g. subject (S) - predicate (P) - object (O))

Now if I want to, for some reason, annotate any of these triples (nodes), than I'd like to keep links to them that I can use in web documents.

**Here are some conditions:**

1) Such link must be in a form of one line of text

2) Such link should be easily parseable both by machine and person

3) Sections of such links should be delimited

4) Such link must be easy to grep, which IMO means they should be wrapped in some distinct letters or characters to make them easy to regex from any web or other document

5) Such link can be used in URL pathnames or query strings, thus has to comply with URL syntax

6) Characters used in such link must not be reserved for URL pathnames, query strings or hashes (e.g. not "/", ";" "?", "#")

**My ideas so far were as follows:**

a) Start and end such link with some distinct, constant set of letters, e.g. STK_....._OVRFLW

b) Separate sections with dashes "-", e.g. Subject-Predicate-Object

So it would look like:

```
STK_S1234-P123-O1234_OVRFLW
```

You have better ideas?

Comment: are you familiar with RDF and RDFa ? I think that what you describe is pretty close to  already existing Semantic Web technologies. See ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Description_Framework  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDFa

Comment: Yes I am familiar with them. But problem is, current RDF style UID's are hard to pass via POST (for example, because of the # characters they use) and XML style notations are harder to parse using Javascript (if I was to use some JS plug-in for detecting RDF-like links on a page)

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @msalvadores on this one - this seems to be a classic use of semantic web / linked data (albeit in a rather complex form), and your example seems to be more related to URI design rather than anthing else.

# is dealt with extensively in the semantic web lit, also there are javascript libraries for querying rdf through sparql - it just makes more sense to stick with the standard.

To link to a triple, the standard method is to use reification - essentially naming a triple (to keep with the triple model, it ends up creating 4 triples, but I would consider it the "correct" method in this situation). There is also the "named graph" method, which isn't a standard, but probably has more widespread adoption.

The link will be 1 line of text

It will be easily machine parsable, to make it human parsable, it might be necessary to give some thought to URI design.

Delimitation is once again on URI design

easy grepping - URI design

URL syntax - tick

no "/", ";" "?", "#" - I would try to incorporate it into a url instead of pushing it out

I would consider www.stackoverflow.com/statement/S1234_P123_O123, where S1234 etc. are unique labels (I don't necessarily agree with human readable uris, but I guess they'll have to stay until humans don't have to read uris). The beautiful thing is that it should dereference and give a nice human vs machine readable representation

Comment: problems with ? and # in URL is that # is not interpreted server side at all and ? denounces that what follows is a query. 

Funny thing is that I posted that question in 2010 and I am back with a similar question. I need to create URIs for all items on the site, URIs that will not change over time even if URL structure changes, and would somehow resolve to the current URLs.